# Java Method Return Type Specialisation

Tags: java, polymorphism

Suppose I have a collection which stores generic types, e.g.

```
public class MyCollection<T> {
    public T getNext()
    {
        //Remove T from list
        //Return T
    }
}
```

I am using this collection to store subtypes, e.g.

```
public class NormalPerson extends Human {
    public void beNice() { }
}
public class Murderer extends Human {
    public void kill() { }
}

...

MyCollection<Human> people = new MyCollection<>();

people.add(new NormalPerson());
people.add(new Murderer());
```

I would like to call methods specific to each subtype. e.g.

```
Human person = people.getNext();
switch(person.getType()) {
    case NORMAL:
        person.beNice(); //Symbol not found
        break;
    case MURDERER:
        person.kill(); //Symbol not found
        break;
}
```

However I can't unless I cast, e.g.

```
switch(people.getNext().getType()) {
    case NORMAL:
        NormalPerson person = (NormalPerson)people.getNext();
        person.beNice();
        break;
```

Is casting the only way to have this work? Am I going about this the wrong way?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

If you want a Human to be able to do both actions, you need to declare this in Human.

A simpler approach is to have a generic `act` method which cause a Person to be nice and a murder to kill.  This way the caller doesn't need to know what action the Human will take.

Answer (score 0):

You are going about it in the wrong way. The calling code shouldn't check or even care about the exact type of the object, it should be enough to know that it is s ome kind of `Human`.

A common way to solve this is to have a more generic name for the method, maybe `Human#doAction()`, and let each class extending `Human` define its specialized behavior by overriding that method. This way you can call the same method no matter which `Human` you have, which greatly simplifies your code.

Answer (score 0):

Compiler can only understand reference type. So that when you write Human, compiler will try to look for the method in the Human class which it will not be able to find as it is actually something else which implements Human and the method that is trying to be called is not in the Human itself.

What you can do is you can use instanceof operator to check what type of the object it actually is otherwise casting is the only way to go.

For e.g.

```
Human h=new Killer();

if(h instanceof Killer)
{
    (Killer)h.kill();
}
```

Hope this helps.